# TFS Project Collections URL set to old Server after Migration to New Environment

Tags: azure, tfs, migration, tfsbuild, database-migration

I am currently working on a TFS Migration from two existing servers, one for TFS and one for our SQL Database, into a new single Azure Server that holds both the SQL Database as well as the TFS Application-Tier/Admin Console.

Our SQL migration went on without an issue and currently our existing server's Admin Console is running using the SQL Databases set up in the new Azure Server.  We have attempted to migrate the TFS Configuration into our Azure Server however our project collection URLs are still set to the old, existing server.

We have tried detaching the Project Collections in our old environment, then reconfigurating our new Azure Admin Console, but the URL for our collection still reads as the old environment.  Everything else in the environment seems to have migrated correctly.  Can someone explain why that might be happening?

Below is the screen I am curious about.  The `URL:` field is still set to the old environment, and the `SQL Server instance` is correctly in the new Azure Database.

[image: example]

Comment: Did you read the documentation on how to perform TFS migrations?

Comment: Yes, I have been following the steps listed out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT yes, that is a big step that I had ended up skipping my accident..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the application-tier node and update Team Foundation Server URLs. Check the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware#update-tfs-urls

Comment: Thank you, this is a step that I had somehow missed while following the Microsoft documentation..